# Rails3: How do I visit a subdomain in a steak(rspec) spec using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to access user1.application.local.dev/panel/new from a steak spec.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1. Set up a local DNS.

http://intridea.com/2010/6/2/using-bind-locally-on-os-x-for-easy-access-to-subdomains?blog=company

Step 2. Use a Capybara driver that support subdomains.

Either Selenium or Akephalos would do the trick.

Create  spec/support/custom_env and put this content in it:

```
#Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_driver = :akephalos
Capybara.app_host = 'http://davinci.testing.dev:8082'
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.server_port = 8082
```

Select the capybara driver that you want, either Selenium or akpehalos or whatever you want, except rack-test (default)

Put the domain and port of you choice, of course.

Step 3:

Add the config.before block to your spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each do 
    Capybara.app_host = "http://davinci.testing.dev:8082"
  end
end

Put the domain and port of you choice, of course.

Step 4:

Add a helper to switch subdomains.

Spec/acceptance/support/helpers.rb

```
def switch_to_subdomain(subdomain)
   Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.davinci.testing.dev:8082"
end
```

Put the domain and port of you choice, of course.

Step 5. Use the helper method in your spec.

Now every-time you want to change of subdomain you do:

```
scenario "Show school" do                        
   school = School.make!(:name=>"perico")
   switch_to_subdomain(school.name)    
   visit("/")                      
   page.has_content?("Welcome to perico")
end
```

Comment: the answer was really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

This is a Capybara question. Set the `default_host` when you need it

```
Capybara.default_host = 'sub.domain.com'
```

Comment: This only works if you are not using rack-test. It works with Selenium and Akephalos.